# If $C\cap D=\emptyset$ Prove that $f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)=\emptyset$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is this the proper way to go about proving this? By showing $C\cap D$=$f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)=\emptyset$?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I don't have any other way of getting feedback for my proofs and I want to improve.

> Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function, $C$,$D$ subsets of $Y$.
>
> If $C\cap D=\emptyset$
>
> Prove that $f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)=\emptyset$

i)Assume $x \in f^c(C \cap D)$.

Then $f(x)\in C \cap D$ so that $f(x) \in C$ and $f(x)\in D$.
Since $f(x)\in C$, $x \in f^c(C)$.

Since $f(x)\in D$, $x \in f^c(D)$.

Since $x \in f^c(D)$ and $x \in f^c(D)$ it follows that $x\in f^c(C) \cap f^c(D)$.

ii)On the other hand, assume $x \in f^c(C) \cap f^c(D)$.

Then $f(x)\in C$ and $f(x)\in D$.

Thus, $f(x) \in C \cap D$ so that $x \in f^c(C \cap D)$.

Comment: what do you mean by $f^c(A)$ ? Is it $f^{-1}(A)$ or $f(A)^c$ (i.e. the complementary of $f(A)$) ?

Comment: I believe its like $f^{-1}(C)$@Surb

Comment: your proof is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first line in i) is confusing since if $C\cap D=\emptyset$ then $x \in f^c(C \cap D)$ does not even exist.

I would write something like this:

assume ac. $f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)\neq \emptyset$ (so the NEGATION of what we are trying to prove)

then $\exists_{x \in X} x \in f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)$

$\exists_{x \in X} x \in f^c(C) \wedge x \in f^c(D)$

$\exists_{f(x) \in Y} f(x) \in C \wedge f(x) \in D$

$C\cap D\neq \emptyset$ which contradicts previous assumption.

Therefor in fact must be true that $f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)= \emptyset$

EDIT:
ok, i just realized what you did there.

You actually showed that $f^c(C)\cap f^c(D)=f^c(C\cap D)$ which is True for any function, however has noting to do with empty sets or your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost a tautology. Anyway, let $C\cap D=\emptyset$ and suppose by contradiction that $$f^{-1}(C\cap D)\neq\emptyset.$$
Then, there is a $x\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $f(x)\in C\cap D$, which is impossible since $C\cap D=\emptyset.$